# How can I construct a can.Map with computed values that behave like normal attributes?

Tags: canjs, canjs-map

Let's say I have a map:

```
map = new can.Map({foo: 'bar'})
```

and I want to bind the value of `foo` in another map.  I could do:

```
otherMap = new can.Map({fizzle: map.compute('foo')})
```

but this doesn't behave the way I would expect.

1. I would expect `otherMap.attr('fizzle')` to return `bar`, but instead it returns a function.  I have to call `otherMap.attr('fizzle')()` instead.
2. I would expect to be able to change the value by calling `otherMap.attr('fizzle', 'moo')`, but this doesn't change the computed value.  Instead, if I want to change the underlying value, I have to call `otherMap.attr('fizzle')('moo')`.

Is there a way to create a map with computed values that behave like normal attributes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the [define plugin](http://canjs.com/docs/can.Map.prototype.define.html) which makes it easy to create computed getters and setters without having to explicitly create computes. In your example like this:

```
var map = new can.Map({
    foo: 'bar',
    baz: 'bla'
});

var OtherMap = can.Map.extend({
    define: {
        fizzle: {
            get: function() {
                return map.attr('foo') + '/' + map.attr('baz');
            },
            set: function(value) {
                map.attr('foo', value);
            }
        }
    } });

var other = new OtherMap();

console.log(other.attr('fizzle'));

other.attr('fizzle', 'something');
console.log(map.attr('foo'));
```

Demo in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qwnytkee/).